# O que seria um NuGet?

Tags: .net, terminologia, nuget

Notei que em vários programas e em vários locais se usam **NuGet**, eu mesmo já tive que usar um, mas usei sem saber a definição do mesmo, posso dizer que seria uma extensão?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É um gerenciador de pacotes que ajuda você administrar os componentes que precisa quando está desenvolvendo para o .NET.

É muito comum as linguagens trazerem este tipo de software porque hoje temos muitos componentes, com muitas dependências, atualizações frequentes. E é mais comum termos um *core* mais enxuto e ir adicionando o que cada um precisa sob demanda. Exemplos de "concorrentes": npm, Chocolatey, Maven, RubyGems, Cargo, etc.

Cada linguagem ou ecossistema costuma ter suas peculiaridades, integrações, então algo universal é um pouco difícil, mas seria o ideal, apesar de que as comunidades nunca concordariam em abrir mão de alguma coisa para ficar universal, ainda mais agora que se acostumaram com suas ferramentas.

Assim você tem uma ferramenta que faz o grosso do trabalho braçal de forma padronizada, e permite que um repositório central cânone exista e de lá sejam pegos os componentes necessários. O que facilita para os criadores de componentes por ter algo padrão e centralizado também.

Obviamente que o gerenciador serve também para os produtores de componentes gerenciarem seus pacotes.

Ele pode ser usado em linha de comando ou integrado com ambientes de desenvolvimento. Atende bem a cultura de DevOps ,mas não só.

[Site oficial](https://www.nuget.org/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Link para detalhes: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/nuget/what-is-nuget